# GMF - model a Class that can contain a component of itself

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf-ecore, eclipse-gmf

since two days i am testing a little with EMF and GMF for the eclipse IDE.

My aim is to model a diagram with a class, that can contain instances of itself (in the generated editor).

In my *.ecore file for testing i have a class DivisionDiagram which is referenced with a class Division - this class should have the ability, that instances of it can contain instances of this class - for example to represent divisions and subdivisions in an enterprise.

I tried to create two references (parent and children) from Division to Division, but later when the editor is generated and opened, i cant drag a division into a division. (i dont want to represent the relation between divisions with an arrow or line - that works fine)

Whats wrong?

Thanks and nice weekend :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These links were useful and hlped a lot:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/GMF_MapModel_Hints#Endless.2Frecursive_hierarchies

http://gmfsamples.tuxfamily.org/wiki/doku.php?id=gmf_tutorial2